# Matlab: opening propertyeditor or plotbrowser forces correct textbox annotation; annotation fails without it

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a generally happily running program that takes files, plots them, spits out a pdf (letter size). I use annotations to put in a title above a set of three subplots, and to use as a footer with file info and date. I would like the title to be at the top of the page, filling up from margin to margin, centered.

I have two ways of running the program: in 'batch' mode and 'interactive' mode. When in 'interactive' mode, I create the figure with a simple `figure()` command. When in 'batch' mode, I create the figure with `figure('visible','off')`. Here is my command for making the annotation:

```
annotation(obj.hFigure(f),'textbox',[0 0.9 1 0.1],...
    'String',title,...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center',...
    'FontSize',18,...
    'LineStyle','none',...
    'FitBoxToText','off');
```

Here, "obj.hFigure(f)" is simply a handle to the figure I am currently processing. As you can see, I place the figure near the top of the figure, and make sure that the text runs off the bottom of the box (in case it is larger).

My problem is with margins on the above annotation. In batch mode (no figures showing), I get 10% or so margins on either side of the text, which ruins the layout. In interactive mode (figures show up), I don't get the margins: the text correctly flows from one edge to the other.

I have narrowed down the problem to the following: I can get the correct response to the ps printing in batch mode if I make the figures visible (`figure('visible','on')`) *AND* open up

```
propertyeditor(gcf);
plotbrowser(gcf);
```

after each figure is plotted. This makes the program take about twice as long (which isn't a huge deal). But what I don't understand is: what do those two commands do that `drawnow` or `refresh` don't accomplish?!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about your specific case, but when encountering this kind of problem in the past I have had great success by explicitly setting the figure size with:

```
set(gcf, 'Position', [100  100  300 300])
```

and then, before printing/saving setting the PaperPositionMode to auto, which seems to force the printed figure to be the same size as the one shown on screen:

```
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')
```